# Single and Archive Pages with Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy, register-taxonomy

I have a custom post type

```
    // Set other options for Custom Post Type
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'document', 'ecse' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Upload Documents', 'ecse' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'excerpt' ,'thumbnail','page-attributes','tags'),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy.
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'sources' ),
      'capability_type'     => 'page',
```

And I have custom taxonomies for it

```
register_taxonomy( 'sources',...[ ...  'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => [
          'hierarchical' => true,
          "with_front" => false,
          'ep_mask' => EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES,
          'slug' => '/%sources%/'

register_taxonomy( 'forms', 'documents',[
      'has_archive' => true,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'rewrite' => [
        'hierarchical' => true,
        "with_front" => false,
        'ep_mask' => EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES,
        'slug' => '/documents/%postname%/'
      ],
      'show_in_menu' => false,
      'query_var' => true,
    ]);
```

I'm able to get the archive page to display a paginated list of the post type.... But the permalink for the single post type is being malformed

The base for my taxonomy permalink is `http://xxxx/documents/%sources%/` where **sources** is the taxonomy if I use `http://xxxx/documents/%sources%/%postname%/` Then the single page works....but I lose the "archive pagination" thus `http://xxxx/documents/%sources%/page/2/` doesn't work.

How do I get both sinlge and archive pages to work for custom post types?

Comment: What **slug** (`documents`?) and **rewrite** parameters are used in `register_post_type()`?

Answer (score -1):

WordPress can handle this automatically by creating a page called
archive-CustomPostTypePage.php through register_post_type() function.

eg. **archive**-documents.php

You need to register your post type in the functions and the name has to be the same as the php file name above eg:

```
register_post_type('documents', array(
    // YOUR ARRAY HERE
));
```